# Element returning null after FadeIn/FadeOut

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm fading in an element with jquery:

```
$("#bookcase_container").fadeOut( function(){
  $("#bookcase_container").html("<canvas id='shelf_canvas'></canvas>").fadeIn();
});
loadCanvasEditor();
```

And then in the canvas editor I try to set the height of the canvas element like so:

```
function loadCanvasEditor(){
  document.getElementById("shelf_canvas").height = "900px";
}
```

But it I get an error stating that shelf_canvas is null. I've also tried using pure jquery, but then I get no results (no error messages or altered resolution):

```
$("#shelf_canvas").height(900);
```

I've also tried using .ready() and onload for shelf_canvas as well as $(document), but still no results. This code works fine if I don't use the fadeOut/fadeIn. What could be going wrong?

Comment: The animation is asynchronous, so your canvas element won't be present when you are  calling loadCanvasEditor.

Comment: True, and that's why I tried using $("shelf_canvas").ready(...). Unfortunately, that didn't work. Is there another way to wait for it to load?

Comment: Can't you just put he loadCanvasEditor-call into the callback? In case not I'd opt for $.Deferred

Comment: Yes, if you do as m90 says, and put the loadCanvasEditor function call into the callback, it should do what you want.  [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QhGU9/)

Comment: The callback method works. Curiously, I'd tried using a callback with the fadeIn (which made more sense to me at the time) and it didn't work. Calling from fadeOut works, though. If you put this in an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fadeOut` animation you are using is an async operation. Therefore the HTML you are inserting into the DOM after the animation is finished is not accessible when you are trying to call your `loadCanvasEditor` function. If you incorporate this call into to the callback things should work as expected:

```
$("#bookcase_container").fadeOut( function(){

  $("#bookcase_container").html("<canvas id='shelf_canvas'></canvas>").fadeIn();
  loadCanvasEditor();

});
```

*BONUS possibility*: Use the `promise`-interface that jQuery-animations expose (useful in more complex cases with lots and lots of elements):

```
$("#bookcase_container").fadeOut( function(){

  $("#bookcase_container").html("<canvas id='shelf_canvas'></canvas>").fadeIn();

}).promise().done(function(){

   loadCanvasEditor();

});
```

See **[a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnLm5/1/)** for that approach.

**[Docs on both cases](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function)** are available on the page for `.fadeIn()`